# C++ access violation in msvc but not gcc for multiple inheritance and cast

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, virtual-inheritance, memory-layout, type-punning

I have a fairly large project with multiple interfaces and implementations.
The code was implemented on a linux environment using g++ (5.4 I think). After porting the code to Windows and running it with VS15 (MSVC v140) I got an access violation after trying to access a casted pointer.

This is the inheritance hierarchy in the code below:

```
                 A    
                / \  
     virtual   /   \   
              /     |
             B      |
             |      | virtual
             C      |
             |      |
             \      / 
              \    /
                D
```

In the real code the inheritance design includes more classes so please don't pick on why this is the way I inherit from `A`.
I've narrowed down the code to present only what is necessary.

The following runs with gcc and prints `foo called` twice [(Live demo on rextester)](http://rextester.com/ZNX84854), but with msvc on the second call to `foo` crashes with access violation [(Live demo on rextester)](http://rextester.com/TYUB61269)

```
#include <iostream>

class A{};

class B : public virtual A{};

class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class D : public virtual A, public C
{
public:
    bool convert(int id, B** ext)
    {
        if (id == 1)
        {
            *ext = (C*)this;
            return true;
        }

        if (id == 42)
        {
            C** pp_ext = (C**)(ext);
            *pp_ext = (C*)this;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "foo called" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    D s;
    C* foo_ext = nullptr;
    s.convert(42, (B**)&foo_ext);
    foo_ext->foo();

    foo_ext = nullptr;
    s.convert(1, (B**)&foo_ext);
    foo_ext->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

First - Am I missing a fundamental error in the `*ext = (C*)this;` conversion?

Second - Why is this code different in the two compilers?

**EDIT**:

1. This code uses pointers, pointers to pointers and is built with this inheritance for good reasons (one of which is ABI compliant interface).
2. `dynamic_cast` doesn't change the behavior in this case.
3. If I call `static_cast<C*>(*ext)->foo();` after `*ext = (C*)this;` it will call foo, but fail after returning from `convert`. This is something I have already understood and this is what made me understand that the solution for `42` is a (good?) solution.

Comment: Stop using c-style casts and too much stars.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Comment: And this is not a good reason to down vote this question.

Comment: @LogicStuff is right, C-style casts will only work for interfaces in trivial cases. For multiple inheritance `dynamic_cast` and friends is a must.

Comment: @LogicStuff, What are the benefits of using reinterpret_cast<B**> here?

Comment: dynamic_cast does not change anything in this case, I think you are missing whatever I'm missing

Comment: Why the difference between compilers? Most likely, undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: @FredLarson do you know where?

Comment: Step through the program in the debugger and check the values of the variables.

Comment: No. But when there's a difference between compilers, that's often the case.

Comment: I will update my question so other people won't answer the same

Comment: I suspect your double pointer casts aren't legal. I can't convert them to either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` without a compile error.

Comment: @FredLarson I don't think there exists a way to have static_cast or dynamic_cast work for a pointer to pointer

Comment: It's funny that changing the convert function parameter to C** will actually work in MSVC. Or moving your virtual foo to A from B will also fix the issue.

Comment: Cast your `D*` `this` to both a `C*` and `B*` and look at the addresses. They might not be the same!

Comment: "`(C*)this`" why do you believe you need this cast? What are you trying to accomplish with this upcast?

Comment: You should use `dynamic_cast` for polymorphic casts, so that you get well-defined error behaviour in case of a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with inheritance, and especially multiple inheritance, you should really try to avoid casts entirely. But if you have to cast, then use either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`. That way the compiler will help you avoid invalid conversions. If you do anything else, then you have to understand all the details of C++ as well as or better than the compiler itself! Otherwise you risk easily making mistakes. Like you did here.

Try modifying your main to something like:

```
int main()
{
    D s;

    A* a = &s;
    B* b = &s;
    C* c = &s;
    std::cout << "A address = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B address = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C address = " << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "D address = " << &s << std::endl;

    C* foo_ext = nullptr;
    s.convert(42, (B**)&foo_ext);
    std::cout << "foo_ext = " << foo_ext << std::endl;
    foo_ext->foo();

    foo_ext = nullptr;
    s.convert(1, (B**)&foo_ext);
    std::cout << "foo_ext = " << foo_ext << std::endl;
    foo_ext->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Running that up until the crash, I get:

```
A address = 0037FEA0
B address = 0037FE9C
C address = 0037FE98
D address = 0037FE98
foo_ext = 0037FE98
foo called
foo_ext = 0037FE9C
```

Obviously in the second case `foo_ext` is not being set to the proper `C` address of the object but instead to the `B` part. In practice then, the call to `foo()` might be going through an incorrect or non-existent virtual table pointer, thus the crash.

Now, why does the first case work? Well, cutting it down to the minimum of what's happening, you've effectively done:

```
C* foo_ext = nullptr;
C** ppc = &foo_ext;
B** ppb = (B**)ppc;
C** pp_ext = (C**)ppb;
*pp_ext = &s;
```

So it starts with a `C` pointer and ends with a `C` pointers. And the compiler knows how to properly shift a `D` pointer to be `C` pointer. (Derived to base conversion. The compiler doesn't need a cast to do that.)

However in the second case you effectively have:

```
C* foo_ext = nullptr;
C** ppc = &foo_ext;
B** ext = (B**)ppc;
*ext = &s;
```

So at the last line the compiler is shifting a `D` pointer to become a `B` pointer. But really that address is ending up back in a `C` pointer. So it has been shifted too far back up the inheritance hierarchy!

---

Now, how to fix you program... Well, the basic idea of course is to get rid of most of the casting and replace the remaining couple spots with static or dynamic casts. Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

class B : public virtual A {};

class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class D : public virtual A, public C
{
public:
    bool convert(int id, B** ext)
    {
        if (id == 1)
        {
            *ext = this;
            return true;
        }

        if (id == 42)
        {
            *ext = this;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "foo called" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    D s;

    A* a = &s;
    B* b = &s;
    C* c = &s;
    std::cout << "A address = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B address = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C address = " << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "D address = " << &s << std::endl;

    B* b_pointer = nullptr;
    C* foo_ext = nullptr;
    s.convert(42, &b_pointer);
    foo_ext = static_cast<C*>(b_pointer);
    std::cout << "foo_ext = " << foo_ext << std::endl;
    foo_ext->foo();

    b_pointer = nullptr;
    foo_ext = nullptr;
    s.convert(1, &b_pointer);
    foo_ext = static_cast<C*>(b_pointer);
    std::cout << "foo_ext = " << foo_ext << std::endl;
    foo_ext->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

This should run fine with all the expected output. The static casts allow the compiler to properly situate the pointers as per their types. (And in this limited example we of course know what all the types really are, so we don't have to bother with dynamic cast.)

I assume this example was based on a real world problem. I can't say whether this exact solution is appropriate for that (since obviously I don't know the real situation). But the principle is sound: don't lie to the compiler by forcing questionable casts. Let it automatically convert whenever possible, and resort only to `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I have also reproduced this behavior without multiple inheritance, since the real problem is the cast to B** before the call. Do you have any idea what causes the difference in compilers?

Comment: @ZivS Different compilers can make different choices as to the memory layout of the parts of the object. Having classes with no members particularly can allow optimizations where the base part of the object doesn't take up any space within the total size of the derived object. So in other works the pointers to derived and base end up being the same address. Notice there's an instance of that in my results with the C and D addresses. Maybe on g++ that happens for B and C, and so your code ends up working despite the bad cast. I wouldn't want to rely on that though.

Comment: I my real code D inherint from C1, C2... and also some other types. In this case D inherits from C and an A, isn't that MI?

Answer (score 1):

The first runtime problem comes at:

```
s.convert(42, (B**)&foo_ext);
```

`foo_ext` has type `C *`.  So the use of `*ext` inside `convert` commits a strict aliasing violation, by accessing the memory of a `C *` as if it were a `B *`  . In general, pointers to different types may have different size and representation; but even if they don't, it is still not permitted to alias them.

Although the strict aliasing rule has an exception for accessing base classes, that doesn't extend to base class pointers.

MSVC probably doesn't enforce strict aliasing in that situation (in fact some things in the Windows API rely on that behaviour).  But if you want to write portable code, it would be a good idea to not rely on strict aliasing violations.

---

The `convert` function uses pass-by-pointer. There is never a need for this in C++. You can use pass-by-reference as a language feature instead.  This reduces the chance of making mistakes -- some of the mistakes in your code actually can't even be expressed in reference notation.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{};

class B : public virtual A{};

class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class D : public virtual A, public C
{
public:
    bool convert(int id, B*& ext)
    {
        if (id == 1)
        {
            ext = static_cast<C *>(this);  // note: redundant cast
            return true;
        }

        if (id == 42)
        {
            ext = this;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "foo called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    D s;
    B* foo_ext_b;
    C* foo_ext;

    foo_ext_b = nullptr;

    if ( !s.convert(42, foo_ext_b) )
        throw std::runtime_error("convert42 failed");

    foo_ext = static_cast<C *>(foo_ext_b);
    foo_ext->foo();

    foo_ext_b  = nullptr;

    if ( !s.convert(1, foo_ext_b) )
        throw std::runtime_error("convert1 failed");

    foo_ext = static_cast<C *>(foo_ext_b);
    foo_ext->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that using `foo_ext = static_cast<C *>(foo_ext_b);` , in general, is error-prone. There will be silent undefined behaviour if `convert` "returned" a `B *` that did not happen to point to a `B` which is a base class of a `C` instance.

For safety you would use `dynamic_cast` instead. But to allow dynamic_cast to work, the base class must have at least one virtual function.  You could add a virtual destructor to `B` or `A`.

Comment: Pointers to classes need to have the same size.